# CUDA matrix class

Tags: c++, object-oriented, matrix, cuda

I started to work on this  CUDA C matrix class to learn both the object oriented programming in C++ and to learn CUDA. The initial goal of this project was to make a matrix class that can have almost similar syntax as MATLAB has. However, on the way I faced one big issue which was number the of host to device and the device to host data transfer calls. I was able to improve the situation by separating `lvalue` and `rvalue` references and move semantics. Currently I am at the stage where I have a working code which needs to be optimized.

I am looking for the answers of following questions:

- Not being a developer or a computer science major I need to know how 
  well written is this code?
- Is my approach of error and exception handling correct or not? Is
  there a better way? (Look at `imp_includes.hcu`, `cu_error_list.cu` and 
  `error_check.cu`)
- I know that the way i am calculating the dimensions of the thread block 
  in `block_dim.cu` is very naive. I would like to know if there is a 
  better way to identify the dimensions of the thread block 
  automatically.
- The solution I came up with to reduce the number of copy constructor 
  calls now require me to have multiple overloads to  separate `lavlue` 
  and `rvalue` references. Is there a more simpler way to tackle this 
  problem?
- To further improve the data transfer performance, I am thinking of 
  using CUDA streams. I would like to have some comments on how useful it 
  can be in this specific scenario.
- I am not expecting anyone to review the complete library. However, if 
  there is any bit of code that can be improved, please let me know.

Following are the minimal versions of the files that I think will be enough to answer my questions. The complete code can be found [here](https://github.com/vxj9800/cuda-matrix-lib).

### cu_mat.hcu ## - Class header

```
#ifndef CU_MAT_HCU_
#define CU_MAT_HCU_

#include "imp_includes.hcu"

class cu_mat {
protected:
    size_t n_rows=0, n_cols=0;
    double *p=NULL;
    cu_mat(){}                                                                                              // Default constructor
    cu_mat(const size_t &r, const size_t &c, const double &n);                                              // Two argument constructor with initialization
    void init(const size_t &r, const size_t &c);                                                            // Two argument memory allocation with initialization

public:
    /***** Constructors *****/
    cu_mat(const cu_mat &to_b_copied);                                                                      // Copy constructor
    cu_mat(const std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<double>> &mat);                                // Single argument constructor with 'double' values
    cu_mat(const std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<cu_mat>> &mat);                                        // Single argument constructor with 'cu_mat' values
    cu_mat(const double &n);                                                                                // Single value constructor
    cu_mat(cu_mat&& to_be_moved);                                                                           // Move constructor



    /***** Operators *****/ // Add an ultimate '()' operator.
//  cu_mat operator()(const cu_mat rows, const cu_mat cols);                                                // Sub-matrix access with 'cu_mat'
    cu_mat operator()(const size_t &idx) const;                                                             // Matrix element access based on index
    cu_mat operator()(const size_t &r, const size_t &c) const;                                                  // Matrix element access
    cu_mat operator()(const size_t &r_begin, const size_t &r_end, const size_t &c_begin, const size_t &c_end) const;    // Sub-matrix access

    cu_mat& operator=(const cu_mat &b);                                                                     // Assignment operator to copy 'cu_mat'
    cu_mat& operator=(cu_mat &&b);                                                                  // Assignment operator to move 'cu_mat'                                                                     // Assignment operator for 'double' to avoid implicit type casting

    cu_mat operator*(const cu_mat &b) const &;                                                                      // Matrix multiplication operator
    cu_mat operator*(cu_mat &&b) const &;                                                                       // Matrix multiplication operator
    cu_mat operator*(const cu_mat &b) &&;                                                                       // Matrix multiplication operator
    cu_mat operator*(cu_mat &&b) &&;                                                                    // Matrix multiplication operator

    cu_mat operator>(const cu_mat &b) const &;                                                                      // Greater than operator
    cu_mat operator>(cu_mat &&b) const &;                                                                       // Greater than operator
    cu_mat operator>(const cu_mat &b) &&;                                                                       // Greater than operator
    cu_mat operator>(cu_mat &&b) &&;                                                                        // Greater than operator

    explicit operator double();                                                                             // Type conversion from cu_mat to double



    /***** Member functions *****/ // Add an ultimate replace function
    cu_mat div(const cu_mat &b) const &;                                                                            // Element wise division
    cu_mat div(cu_mat &&b) const &;                                                                         // Element wise division
    cu_mat div(const cu_mat &b) &&;                                                                         // Element wise division
    cu_mat div(cu_mat &&b) &&;                                                                          // Element wise division

    cu_mat mult(const cu_mat &b) const &;                                                                           // Element wise multiplication
    cu_mat mult(cu_mat &&b) const &;                                                                            // Element wise multiplication
    cu_mat mult(const cu_mat &b) &&;                                                                            // Element wise multiplication
    cu_mat mult(cu_mat &&b) &&;                                                                         // Element wise multiplication

    cu_mat pow(const double &n) const &;                                                                            // Element wise power
    cu_mat pow(const double &n) &&;                                                                         // Element wise power

    void replace(const size_t &r, const size_t &c, const cu_mat &n);                                        // Replace an element with a 'cu_mat' value

    void replace(const size_t &r_begin, const size_t &r_end, const size_t &c_begin, const size_t &c_end, const cu_mat &n);  // Replace submatrix with a 'cu_mat' matrix

    void get();                                                                                 // Print matrix data

    void print(std::ofstream &print);                                                                       // Print matrix to a file

    size_t rows();                                                                                          // Get number of rows
    size_t rows() const;                                                                                            // Get number of rows

    size_t cols();                                                                                          // Get number of columns
    size_t cols() const ;                                                                                           // Get number of columns

    double* pointer();                                                                                      // Get GPU memory pointer
    double* pointer() const;                                                                                        // Get GPU memory pointer



    /***** Supported external (friend) functions *****/
    friend cu_mat randn(const size_t &r, const size_t &c);                                                  // Generate a matrix with normalized random numbers
    friend cu_mat randn(const size_t &n);

    friend cu_mat mld(const cu_mat &a, const cu_mat &b);                                                                // Matrix left divide operator
    friend cu_mat mld(const cu_mat &a, cu_mat &&b);                                                             // Matrix left divide operator
    friend cu_mat mld(cu_mat &&a, const cu_mat &b);                                                             // Matrix left divide operator
    friend cu_mat mld(cu_mat &&a, cu_mat &&b);                                                              // Matrix left divide operator

    friend cu_mat eye(const size_t &r, const size_t &c);                                                    // Generate a non-square identity matrix
    friend cu_mat eye(const size_t &n);

    friend cu_mat ones(const size_t &r, const size_t &c);                                                   // Matrix with all values 1
    friend cu_mat ones(const size_t &n);

    friend cu_mat zeros(const size_t &r, const size_t &c);                                                  // Matrix with all values 0
    friend cu_mat zeros(const size_t &n);

    friend cu_mat trans(cu_mat &a);                                                                 // Transpose of the matrix

    friend cu_mat horzcat(cu_mat &a, cu_mat &b);                                                // Horizontal concatenation of two matrices

    friend cu_mat vertcat(cu_mat &a, cu_mat &b);                                                // Vertical concatenation of two matrices

    friend cu_mat stepspace(const double &i, const double &step, const double &f);                          // MATLAB colon operator

    friend bool isscalar(const cu_mat &a);                                                                  // Check if 'cu_mat' object is scalar

    /***** Destructor *****/
    virtual ~cu_mat();
};

/***** Supported external (friend) functions *****/
cu_mat randn(const size_t &r, const size_t &c);                                                 // Generate a matrix with normalized random numbers
cu_mat randn(const size_t &n);

cu_mat mld(const cu_mat &a, const cu_mat &b);                                                               // Matrix left divide operator
cu_mat mld(const cu_mat &a, cu_mat &&b);                                                                // Matrix left divide operator
cu_mat mld(cu_mat &&a, const cu_mat &b);                                                                // Matrix left divide operator
cu_mat mld(cu_mat &&a, cu_mat &&b);                                                             // Matrix left divide operator

cu_mat eye(const size_t &r, const size_t &c);                                                   // Generate a non-square identity matrix
cu_mat eye(const size_t &n);

cu_mat ones(const size_t &r, const size_t &c);                                                  // Matrix with all values 1
cu_mat ones(const size_t &n);

cu_mat zeros(const size_t &r, const size_t &c);                                                 // Matrix with all values 0
cu_mat zeros(const size_t &n);

cu_mat trans(cu_mat &a);                                                                    // Transpose of the matrix

cu_mat horzcat(cu_mat &a, cu_mat &b);                                               // Horizontal concatenation of two matrices

cu_mat vertcat(cu_mat &a, cu_mat &b);                                               // Vertical concatenation of two matrices

cu_mat stepspace(const double &i, const double &step, const double &f);                         // MATLAB colon operator

bool isscalar(const cu_mat &a);                                                                 // Check if 'cu_mat' object is scalar

#endif /* CU_MAT_HCU_ */
```

### cu_mat.cu ## - Member functions, constructors, destructors, operators and friend functions

```
#include "cu_mat.hcu"
//  Constructors
/**************************************   Single argument constructor with 'double' values   *******************************************/
cu_mat::cu_mat(const std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<double>> &mat) : n_rows(mat.size()), n_cols(mat.begin()->size())
{
    // ' -> ' Means:  pointer to an object -> member function. Essentially accessing a member function with the help of a pointer to that object.
    // Define number of rows from the array input. Define number of columns from first row of array input
    // Check if the number of elements in each row are same.
    for(int i = 0; i<n_rows; ++i)
    {
        confirm((mat.begin()+i)->size()==n_cols,"Error: Object initialization failed. Number of elements in each row must be same.");
    }

    // Copy input initializer-list to a new 2D array while making it column major.
    double *m = new double[n_rows*n_cols]();    // Allocate space on CPU memory.
    confirm(m,"Error: Memory allocation failed while initializing the object."); // Check proper allocation.

    for(int i = 0; i<n_rows; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<n_cols; ++j)
        {
            m[j*n_rows+i] = *((mat.begin()+i)->begin()+j);
        }
    }

    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc((void**)&p, n_rows*n_cols*sizeof(double)) ); // Allocate memory on GPU.
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy(p,m,n_rows*n_cols*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) ); // Copy array from CPU to GPU
    delete[] m;
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/**************************************   Single argument constructor with 'cu_mat' values   *******************************************/
__global__ void copymat(double* dest, double* src, size_t bias, size_t src_rows, size_t main_rows_bias, size_t n_ele)
{
    unsigned int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (idx<n_ele)
    dest[bias+idx+idx/src_rows*main_rows_bias] = src[idx];
}
cu_mat::cu_mat(const std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<cu_mat>> &mat)
{
    // Calculate total number of columns
    for(int i = 0; i<mat.begin()->size(); ++i)
        n_cols += ((mat.begin())->begin()+i)->n_cols;

    // Check equal number of rows for horizontal concatenation and calculate total number of rows.
    for(int i = 0; i<mat.size(); ++i)
    {
        size_t cols = ((mat.begin()+i)->begin())->n_cols;
        for(int j = 0; j<(mat.begin()+i)->size()-1; ++j)
        {
            confirm(((mat.begin()+i)->begin()+j)->n_rows==((mat.begin()+i)->begin()+j+1)->n_rows,"Error: Dimensions of arrays being horizontally concatenated are not consistent.");
            cols += ((mat.begin()+i)->begin()+j+1)->n_cols;
        }
        confirm(cols == n_cols,"Error: Dimensions of arrays being vertically concatenated are not consistent.")
        n_rows += ((mat.begin()+i)->begin())->n_rows;
    }

    // Allocate memory and copy data
    if ((n_rows>0)&&(n_cols>0))
    {
        HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc((void**)&p, n_rows*n_cols*sizeof(double)) ); // Allocate memory on GPU.
        size_t bias, src_rows, src_cols;
        size_t main_rows_bias, n_ele, n_threads;
        size_t r_sum = 0, c_sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<mat.size(); ++i){
            for(int j = 0; j<(mat.begin()+i)->size(); ++j){
                bias = c_sum*n_rows+r_sum; src_rows = ((mat.begin()+i)->begin()+j)->n_rows; src_cols = ((mat.begin()+i)->begin()+j)->n_cols;
                main_rows_bias = n_rows-src_rows; n_ele = src_rows*src_cols; n_threads = block_dim(n_ele); c_sum += src_cols;
                copymat<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(p,((mat.begin()+i)->begin()+j)->p,bias,src_rows,main_rows_bias,n_ele);
                HANDLE_ERROR( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
            }
            r_sum += src_rows; c_sum = 0;
        }
    }
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/************************************   Single value constructor   ***********************************************/
cu_mat::cu_mat(const double &n) : n_rows(1), n_cols(1)
{
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc((void**)&p, n_rows*n_cols*sizeof(double)) ); // Allocate memory on GPU.
//    std::cout << p << std::endl;
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy(p,&n,n_rows*n_cols*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) ); // Copy array from CPU to GPU
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/************************************   Copy constructor   ***********************************************/
cu_mat::cu_mat(const cu_mat &to_b_copied) : n_rows(to_b_copied.n_rows), n_cols(to_b_copied.n_cols)
{
//    std::cout << "Copy constructor called." << std::endl;
    if ((n_rows>0)&&(n_cols>0))
    {
        HANDLE_ERROR( cudaFree(p) );
        HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc((void**)&p,n_rows*n_cols*sizeof(double)) ); // Allocate memory on GPU.
        HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy(p,to_b_copied.p,n_rows*n_cols*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice) ); // Copy array from CPU to GPU
    }
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/************************************   Two argument constructor with initialization   ***********************************************/
__global__ void set_data(double* p, const double n, const double n_ele)
{
    unsigned int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (idx<n_ele)
    p[idx] = n;
}
cu_mat::cu_mat(const size_t &r, const size_t &c, const double &n=0) : n_rows(r), n_cols(c)
{
    if ((n_rows>0)&&(n_cols>0))
    {
        HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc((void**)&p, n_rows*n_cols*sizeof(double)) );
        if (n!=0)
        {
            size_t n_ele = n_rows*n_cols;
            size_t n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
            set_data<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(p,n,n_ele);
            HANDLE_ERROR( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
        }
        else
        {
            HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemset(p,0,n_rows*n_cols*sizeof(double)) );
        }
    }
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/************************************   Move constructor   ***********************************************/
cu_mat::cu_mat(cu_mat&& to_b_moved)
{
//    std::cout << "Move constructor called." << std::endl;
    size_t nrows = to_b_moved.n_rows, ncols = to_b_moved.n_cols; double *ptr = to_b_moved.p;
    to_b_moved.n_rows = 0; to_b_moved.n_cols = 0; to_b_moved.p = NULL;
    n_rows = nrows; n_cols = ncols; p = ptr;
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/










//  Operators
/**************************************   Sub-matrix access with 'cu_mat'   *******************************************/
// __global__ void check_integer()
// cu_mat cu_mat::operator()(const cu_mat rows, const cu_mat cols)
// {
//     confirm((rows.n_rows==1) || (rows.n_cols==1), "Error: 'rows' has to be a vector.");
//     confirm((cols.n_rows==1) || (cols.n_cols==1), "Error: 'rows' has to be a vector.");
//     confirm(idx > 0, "Indexing starts from 1 for this library.")
//     confirm(idx <= n_rows*n_cols,"Error: Index exceeds matrix bounds. Matrix has " << n_rows*n_cols << "elements in it.");
//     cu_mat temp(1,1);
//     HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy(temp.p,p+(idx-1),sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice) ); // Copy value from GPU to GPU
//     return temp;
// }
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/**************************************   Matrix element access based on index   *******************************************/
cu_mat cu_mat::operator()(const size_t &idx) const
{
    confirm(idx > 0, "Indexing starts from 1 for this library.")
    confirm(idx <= n_rows*n_cols,"Error: Index exceeds matrix bounds. Matrix has " << n_rows*n_cols << " elements in it.");
    cu_mat temp(1,1);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy(temp.p,p+(idx-1),sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice) ); // Copy value from GPU to GPU
    return std::move(temp);
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/**************************************   Access single element of the matrix   *******************************************/
cu_mat cu_mat::operator()(const size_t &r, const size_t &c) const
{
    confirm((r>0)&&(c>0), "Indexing starts from 1 for this library.")
    confirm((r<=n_rows)&&(c<=n_cols),"Error: Index exceeds matrix bounds. The size of the matrix is " << n_rows << "x" << n_cols << ".");
    cu_mat temp(1,1);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy(temp.p,p+(c-1)*n_rows+r-1,sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice) ); // Copy value from GPU to GPU
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    return std::move(temp);
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/**************************************   Access sub-matrix   *******************************************/
__global__ void submat(double* dest, double* src, size_t bias, size_t dest_rows, size_t main_rows_bias, size_t n_ele)
{
    unsigned int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (idx<n_ele)
    dest[idx] = src[bias+idx+idx/dest_rows*main_rows_bias];
}
cu_mat cu_mat::operator()(const size_t &r_begin, const size_t &r_end, const size_t &c_begin, const size_t &c_end) const
{
    confirm((r_begin>0)&&(c_begin>0), "Indexing starts from 1 for this library.")
    confirm((r_end<=n_rows)&&(c_end<=n_cols),"Error: Index exceeds matrix bounds. The size of the matrix is " << n_rows << "x" << n_cols << ".")
    cu_mat temp(r_end-r_begin+1,c_end-c_begin+1);
    size_t bias = (c_begin-1)*n_rows+r_begin-1;
    size_t main_rows_bias = n_rows-temp.n_rows;
    size_t n_ele = temp.n_rows*temp.n_cols;
    size_t n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
    submat<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(temp.p,p,bias,temp.n_rows,main_rows_bias,n_ele);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    return std::move(temp);
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/***************************************   Assignment operator to copy 'cu_mat'   **************************************/
cu_mat& cu_mat::operator=(const cu_mat &b)
{
//  std::cout << "Copy assignment operator called." << std::endl;
    if ((n_rows*n_cols)!=(b.n_rows*b.n_cols))
    {
        HANDLE_ERROR( cudaFree(p) );
        HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc((void**)&p, b.n_rows*b.n_cols*sizeof(double)) ); // Allocate memory on GPU.
    }
    n_rows = b.n_rows; n_cols = b.n_cols;
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy(p,b.p,n_rows*n_cols*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice) ); // Copy array from GPU to GPU
    return *this;
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/***************************************   Assignment operator to move 'cu_mat'   **************************************/
cu_mat& cu_mat::operator=(cu_mat &&b)
{
//    std::cout << "Move assignment operator called." << std::endl;
    n_rows = b.n_rows; b.n_rows = 0;
    n_cols = b.n_cols; b.n_cols = 0;
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaFree(p) );
    p = b.p; b.p = NULL;
    return *this;
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/***************************************   Matrix multiplication   **************************************/
__global__ void const_mat_mult(double *dest, double *src, double *n, size_t n_ele)
{
    unsigned int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (idx<n_ele)
    dest[idx] = (*n)*src[idx];
}
cu_mat cu_mat::operator*(const cu_mat &b) const &
{
    if (isscalar(*this))
    {
        cu_mat c(b.n_rows,b.n_cols);
        size_t n_ele = c.n_rows*c.n_cols, n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
        const_mat_mult<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(c.p,b.p,p,n_ele);
        return std::move(c);
    }
    else if (isscalar(b))
    {
        cu_mat c(n_rows,n_cols);
        size_t n_ele = c.n_rows*c.n_cols, n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
        const_mat_mult<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(c.p,p,b.p,n_ele);
        return std::move(c);
    }
    else
    {
        confirm(n_cols == b.n_rows,"Error : Matrix multiplication is not possible. Inner matrix dimensions must agree.");
        cu_mat c(n_rows,b.n_cols);
        HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc((void**)&c.p,c.n_rows*c.n_cols*sizeof(double)) ); // Allocate memory on GPU.
        double alf = 1.0, bet = 0;
        cublasHandle_t handle;
        HANDLE_ERROR( cublasCreate(&handle) );
        HANDLE_ERROR( cublasDgemm(handle,CUBLAS_OP_N,CUBLAS_OP_N,n_rows,b.n_cols,n_cols,&alf,p,n_rows,b.p,n_cols,&bet,c.p,n_rows) );
        HANDLE_ERROR( cublasDestroy(handle) );
        return std::move(c);
    }
}
cu_mat cu_mat::operator*(cu_mat &&b) const &
{
    if (isscalar(*this))
    {
        cu_mat c = std::move(b);
        size_t n_ele = c.n_rows*c.n_cols, n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
        const_mat_mult<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(c.p,c.p,p,n_ele);
        return std::move(c);
    }
    else if (isscalar(b))
    {
        cu_mat c(n_rows,n_cols);
        size_t n_ele = c.n_rows*c.n_cols, n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
        const_mat_mult<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(c.p,p,b.p,n_ele);
        return std::move(c);
    }
    else
    {
        confirm(n_cols == b.n_rows,"Error : Matrix multiplication is not possible. Inner matrix dimensions must agree.");
        cu_mat c(n_rows,b.n_cols);
        HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc((void**)&c.p,c.n_rows*c.n_cols*sizeof(double)) ); // Allocate memory on GPU.
        double alf = 1.0, bet = 0;
        cublasHandle_t handle;
        HANDLE_ERROR( cublasCreate(&handle) );
        HANDLE_ERROR( cublasDgemm(handle,CUBLAS_OP_N,CUBLAS_OP_N,n_rows,b.n_cols,n_cols,&alf,p,n_rows,b.p,n_cols,&bet,c.p,n_rows) );
        HANDLE_ERROR( cublasDestroy(handle) );
        return std::move(c);
    }
}
cu_mat cu_mat::operator*(const cu_mat &b)&&
{
    if (isscalar(*this))
    {
        cu_mat c(b.n_rows,b.n_cols);
        size_t n_ele = c.n_rows*c.n_cols, n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
        const_mat_mult<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(c.p,b.p,p,n_ele);
        return std::move(c);
    }
    else if (isscalar(b))
    {
        cu_mat c = std::move(*this);
        size_t n_ele = c.n_rows*c.n_cols, n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
        const_mat_mult<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(c.p,c.p,b.p,n_ele);
        return std::move(c);
    }
    else
    {
        confirm(n_cols == b.n_rows,"Error : Matrix multiplication is not possible. Inner matrix dimensions must agree.");
        cu_mat c(n_rows,b.n_cols);
        HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc((void**)&c.p,c.n_rows*c.n_cols*sizeof(double)) ); // Allocate memory on GPU.
        double alf = 1.0, bet = 0;
        cublasHandle_t handle;
        HANDLE_ERROR( cublasCreate(&handle) );
        HANDLE_ERROR( cublasDgemm(handle,CUBLAS_OP_N,CUBLAS_OP_N,n_rows,b.n_cols,n_cols,&alf,p,n_rows,b.p,n_cols,&bet,c.p,n_rows) );
        HANDLE_ERROR( cublasDestroy(handle) );
        return std::move(c);
    }
}
cu_mat cu_mat::operator*(cu_mat &&b)&&
{
    if (isscalar(*this))
    {
        cu_mat c = std::move(b);
        size_t n_ele = c.n_rows*c.n_cols, n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
        const_mat_mult<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(c.p,c.p,p,n_ele);
        return std::move(c);
    }
    else if (isscalar(b))
    {
        cu_mat c = std::move(*this);
        size_t n_ele = c.n_rows*c.n_cols, n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
        const_mat_mult<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(c.p,c.p,b.p,n_ele);
        return std::move(c);
    }
    else
    {
        confirm(n_cols == b.n_rows,"Error : Matrix multiplication is not possible. Inner matrix dimensions must agree.");
        cu_mat c(n_rows,b.n_cols);
        HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc((void**)&c.p,c.n_rows*c.n_cols*sizeof(double)) ); // Allocate memory on GPU.
        double alf = 1.0, bet = 0;
        cublasHandle_t handle;
        HANDLE_ERROR( cublasCreate(&handle) );
        HANDLE_ERROR( cublasDgemm(handle,CUBLAS_OP_N,CUBLAS_OP_N,n_rows,b.n_cols,n_cols,&alf,p,n_rows,b.p,n_cols,&bet,c.p,n_rows) );
        HANDLE_ERROR( cublasDestroy(handle) );
        return std::move(c);
    }
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/************************************   Greater than operator   ***********************************************/
__global__ void elem_greater(double* a, double* b, double* c, size_t n_ele)
{
    unsigned int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (idx<n_ele)
    c[idx] = (a[idx] > b[idx]);
}
cu_mat cu_mat::operator>(const cu_mat &b) const &
{
    confirm((n_rows == b.n_rows) && (n_cols == b.n_cols),"Error : Boolean check is not possible. Matrices must have same dimensions.");
    cu_mat c(n_rows,n_cols);
    size_t n_ele = c.n_rows*c.n_cols;
    size_t n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
    elem_greater<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(p,b.p,c.p,n_ele);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    return std::move(c);
}
cu_mat cu_mat::operator>(cu_mat &&b) const &
{
    confirm((n_rows == b.n_rows) && (n_cols == b.n_cols),"Error : Boolean check is not possible. Matrices must have same dimensions.");
    cu_mat c = std::move(b);
    size_t n_ele = c.n_rows*c.n_cols;
    size_t n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
    elem_greater<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(p,c.p,c.p,n_ele);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    return std::move(c);
}
cu_mat cu_mat::operator>(const cu_mat &b) &&
{
    confirm((n_rows == b.n_rows) && (n_cols == b.n_cols),"Error : Boolean check is not possible. Matrices must have same dimensions.");
    cu_mat c = std::move(*this);
    size_t n_ele = c.n_rows*c.n_cols;
    size_t n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
    elem_greater<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(c.p,b.p,c.p,n_ele);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    return std::move(c);
}
cu_mat cu_mat::operator>(cu_mat &&b) &&
{
    confirm((n_rows == b.n_rows) && (n_cols == b.n_cols),"Error : Boolean check is not possible. Matrices must have same dimensions.");
    cu_mat c = std::move(*this);
    size_t n_ele = c.n_rows*c.n_cols;
    size_t n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
    elem_greater<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(c.p,b.p,c.p,n_ele);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    return std::move(c);
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/***************************************   Type conversion from cu_mat to double   **************************************/
cu_mat::operator double()
{
    confirm((n_rows==1) && (n_cols==1), "Error: Type conversion is only possible in the case of 1x1 matrix.");
    double val;
    // Copy data from GPU to CPU.
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy(&val,p,sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );
    return std::move(val);
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/









//  Member Functions
/************************************   Two argument memory allocation with initialization   ***********************************************/
void cu_mat::init(const size_t &r, const size_t &c)
{
    n_rows = r; n_cols = c;
    if ((n_rows>0)&&(n_cols>0))
    {
        HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc((void**)&p, n_rows*n_cols*sizeof(double)) );
        HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemset(p,0,n_rows*n_cols*sizeof(double)) );
    }
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/************************************   Element wise division   ***********************************************/
__global__ void elem_div(double* a, double* b, double* c, size_t n_ele)
{
    unsigned int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (idx<n_ele)
    c[idx] = a[idx] / b[idx];
}
cu_mat cu_mat::div(const cu_mat &b) const &
{
    confirm((n_rows == b.n_rows) && (n_cols == b.n_cols),"Error : Matrix multiplication is not possible. Matrices must have same dimensions.");
    cu_mat c(n_rows,n_cols);
    size_t n_ele = c.n_rows*c.n_cols;
    size_t n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
    elem_div<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(p,b.p,c.p,n_ele);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    return std::move(c);
}
cu_mat cu_mat::div(cu_mat &&b) const &
{
    confirm((n_rows == b.n_rows) && (n_cols == b.n_cols),"Error : Matrix multiplication is not possible. Matrices must have same dimensions.");
    cu_mat c = std::move(b);
    size_t n_ele = c.n_rows*c.n_cols;
    size_t n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
    elem_div<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(p,c.p,c.p,n_ele);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    return std::move(c);
}
cu_mat cu_mat::div(const cu_mat &b) &&
{
    confirm((n_rows == b.n_rows) && (n_cols == b.n_cols),"Error : Matrix multiplication is not possible. Matrices must have same dimensions.");
    cu_mat c = std::move(*this);
    size_t n_ele = c.n_rows*c.n_cols;
    size_t n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
    elem_div<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(c.p,b.p,c.p,n_ele);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    return std::move(c);
}
cu_mat cu_mat::div(cu_mat &&b) &&
{
    confirm((n_rows == b.n_rows) && (n_cols == b.n_cols),"Error : Matrix multiplication is not possible. Matrices must have same dimensions.");
    cu_mat c = std::move(*this);
    size_t n_ele = c.n_rows*c.n_cols;
    size_t n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
    elem_div<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(c.p,b.p,c.p,n_ele);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    return std::move(c);
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/************************************   Element wise multiplication   ***********************************************/
__global__ void elem_mult(double* a, double* b, double* c, size_t n_ele)
{
    unsigned int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (idx<n_ele)
    c[idx] = a[idx] * b[idx];
}
cu_mat cu_mat::mult(const cu_mat &b) const &
{
    confirm((n_rows == b.n_rows) && (n_cols == b.n_cols),"Error : Matrix multiplication is not possible. Matrices must have same dimensions.");
    cu_mat c(n_rows,n_cols);
    size_t n_ele = c.n_rows*c.n_cols;
    size_t n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
    elem_mult<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(p,b.p,c.p,n_ele);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    return std::move(c);
}
cu_mat cu_mat::mult(cu_mat &&b) const &
{
    confirm((n_rows == b.n_rows) && (n_cols == b.n_cols),"Error : Matrix multiplication is not possible. Matrices must have same dimensions.");
    cu_mat c = std::move(b);
    size_t n_ele = c.n_rows*c.n_cols;
    size_t n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
    elem_mult<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(p,c.p,c.p,n_ele);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    return std::move(c);
}
cu_mat cu_mat::mult(const cu_mat &b) &&
{
    confirm((n_rows == b.n_rows) && (n_cols == b.n_cols),"Error : Matrix multiplication is not possible. Matrices must have same dimensions.");
    cu_mat c = std::move(*this);
    size_t n_ele = c.n_rows*c.n_cols;
    size_t n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
    elem_mult<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(c.p,b.p,c.p,n_ele);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    return std::move(c);
}
cu_mat cu_mat::mult(cu_mat &&b) &&
{
    confirm((n_rows == b.n_rows) && (n_cols == b.n_cols),"Error : Matrix multiplication is not possible. Matrices must have same dimensions.");
    cu_mat c = std::move(*this);
    size_t n_ele = c.n_rows*c.n_cols;
    size_t n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
    elem_mult<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(c.p,b.p,c.p,n_ele);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    return std::move(c);
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/************************************   Element wise power   ***********************************************/
__global__ void elem_power(double* dest, double* src, double n, size_t n_ele)
{
    unsigned int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (idx<n_ele)
    dest[idx] = pow(src[idx],n);
}
cu_mat cu_mat::pow(const double &n) const &
{
    cu_mat c(n_rows,n_cols);
    size_t n_ele = c.n_rows*c.n_cols;
    size_t n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
    elem_power<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(c.p,p,n,n_ele);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    return std::move(c);
}
cu_mat cu_mat::pow(const double &n) &&
{
    cu_mat c = std::move(*this);
    size_t n_ele = c.n_rows*c.n_cols;
    size_t n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
    elem_power<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(c.p,c.p,n,n_ele);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    return std::move(c);
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/************************************   Replace an element with a 'cu_mat' value   ***********************************************/
void cu_mat::replace(const size_t &r, const size_t &c, const cu_mat &n)
{
    confirm((n.n_rows==1) && (n.n_cols==1),"Error: Value being replaced with has to be scalar.");
    size_t bias = c*n_rows+r, src_rows = 1, src_cols = 1;
    size_t main_rows_bias = n_rows-src_rows, n_ele = src_rows*src_cols, n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
    copymat<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(p,n.p,bias,src_rows,main_rows_bias,n_ele);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/************************************   Replace submatrix with a 'cu_mat' matrix   ***********************************************/
void cu_mat::replace(const size_t &r_begin, const size_t &r_end, const size_t &c_begin, const size_t &c_end, const cu_mat &n)
{
    confirm((r_end<=n_rows) && (c_end<=n_cols),"Error: Index exceeds matrix bounds. The size of the matrix is " << n_rows << "x" << n_cols << ".");
    confirm((n.n_rows==r_end-r_begin+1) && (n.n_cols==c_end-c_begin+1),"Error: Unable to replace the data due to size mismatch.");
    size_t bias = (c_begin-1)*n_rows+r_begin-1, src_rows = n.n_rows, src_cols = n.n_cols;
    size_t main_rows_bias = n_rows-src_rows, n_ele = src_rows*src_cols, n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
    copymat<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(p,n.p,bias,src_rows,main_rows_bias,n_ele);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/************************************   Print matrix data   ***********************************************/
void cu_mat::get()
{
    double *m = new double[n_rows*n_cols]();    // Allocate space on CPU memory.
    confirm(m,"Error: Memory allocation failed in 'get()'.") // Check proper allocation.

    // Copy data from GPU to CPU.
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy(m,p,n_rows*n_cols*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );

    std::cout << std::scientific << std::setprecision(4);
    for(int i = 0; i<n_rows; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<n_cols; ++j)
        {
            std::cout<<m[j*n_rows+i]<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    delete[] m;
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/************************************   Print matrix to a file   ***********************************************/
void cu_mat::print(std::ofstream &print)
{
    double *m = new double[n_rows*n_cols]();    // Allocate space on CPU memory.
    confirm(m,"Error: Memory allocation failed in 'print()'.") // Check proper allocation.

    // Copy data from GPU to CPU.
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy(m,p,n_rows*n_cols*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );

    // Print the matrix
    print << std::scientific << std::setprecision(8);
    for(int i = 0; i<n_rows; ++i)
    {
        print << " ";
        for(int j = 0; j<n_cols; ++j)
        {
            print << " " << m[j*n_rows+i] << " ";
        }
        print << std::endl;
    }
    delete[] m;
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/***************************************   Get number of rows   *****************************************/
size_t cu_mat::rows(){return n_rows;}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/***************************************   Get number of columns   *****************************************/
size_t cu_mat::cols(){return n_cols;}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/***************************************   Get GPU memory pointer   *****************************************/
double* cu_mat::pointer(){return p;}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/***************************************   Get number of rows   *****************************************/
size_t cu_mat::rows() const {return n_rows;}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/***************************************   Get number of columns   *****************************************/
size_t cu_mat::cols() const {return n_cols;}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/***************************************   Get GPU memory pointer   *****************************************/
double* cu_mat::pointer() const {return p;}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/













//  Friend Functions
/**************************************   Matrix with random numbers   ***********************************************/
cu_mat randn(const size_t &r, const size_t &c)
{
    size_t r_new = r, c_new = c;
    if ((r%2!=0)&&(c%2!=0))
    {
        r_new = r+1; c_new = c+1;
    }
    cu_mat a(r_new,c_new);
    curandGenerator_t prng;
    HANDLE_ERROR( curandCreateGenerator(&prng, CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_XORWOW) );
    HANDLE_ERROR( curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed(prng,(unsigned long long) clock()) );
    HANDLE_ERROR( curandGenerateNormalDouble(prng,a.p,a.n_rows*a.n_cols,0.0,1.0) ); //The number of values requested has to be multiple of 2.
    HANDLE_ERROR( curandDestroyGenerator(prng) );
    return std::move(a(1,r,1,c));
}
cu_mat randn(const size_t &n=1){return std::move(randn(n,n));}
/***************************************************************************************************************************/


/****************************************   Identity matrix   *******************************************/
__global__ void eye_mat(double* p, const int r, const int n_ele)
{
    unsigned int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (idx<n_ele)
    {
        p[idx*r+idx] = 1.0;
    }
}
cu_mat eye(const size_t &r, const size_t &c)
{
    cu_mat temp(r,c);
    size_t n_ele = min(r,c);
    size_t n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
    eye_mat<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(temp.p,r,n_ele);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    return std::move(temp);
}
cu_mat eye(const size_t &n){return std::move(eye(n,n));}
/***************************************************************************************************************************/


/*****************************************   Matrix left divide   *****************************************/
cu_mat mld(const cu_mat &a, const cu_mat &b)
{
    return std::move(mld(cu_mat(a),cu_mat(b)));
}
cu_mat mld(const cu_mat &a, cu_mat &&b)
{
    return std::move(mld(cu_mat(a),std::move(b)));
}
cu_mat mld(cu_mat &&a, const cu_mat &b)
{
    return std::move(mld(std::move(a),cu_mat(b)));
}
cu_mat mld(cu_mat &&a, cu_mat &&b) // Adapted from CUSOLVER_Library.pdf QR examples
{
    confirm(a.n_rows == b.n_rows,"Error: 'mld()' operation cannot be performed. Matrix dimensions must agree.")
    cu_mat A = std::move(a), B = std::move(b); // Copy current matrix to a new matrix for calculations.

    double *d_tau = NULL;
    double *d_work = NULL, alf = 1.0;
    int *devInfo = NULL, lwork = 0, info_gpu = 0;
    cusolverDnHandle_t cusolver_handle = NULL;
    cublasHandle_t cublas_handle = NULL;

    // step 1: create cusolver/cublas handle
    HANDLE_ERROR( cusolverDnCreate(&cusolver_handle) );
    HANDLE_ERROR( cublasCreate(&cublas_handle) );

    // step 2: allocate required extra memory on GPU.
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc((void**)&d_tau,sizeof(double)*A.n_cols) );
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc((void**)&devInfo,sizeof(int)) );

    // step 3: query working space of geqrf and ormqr
    HANDLE_ERROR( cusolverDnDgeqrf_bufferSize(cusolver_handle,A.n_rows,A.n_cols,A.p,A.n_rows,&lwork) );
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc((void**)&d_work, sizeof(double)*lwork) );

    // step 4: compute QR factorization
    HANDLE_ERROR( cusolverDnDgeqrf(cusolver_handle,A.n_rows,A.n_cols,A.p,A.n_rows,d_tau,d_work,lwork,devInfo) );
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );
    // check if QR is good or not
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy(&info_gpu, devInfo, sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );
    confirm(info_gpu == 0,"Error: 'mld()' operation cannot be performed. QR decomposition failed.");

    // step 5: compute Q^T*B (CUSOLVER documentation has typos. Follow LAPACK documentation.)
    HANDLE_ERROR( cusolverDnDormqr(cusolver_handle,CUBLAS_SIDE_LEFT,CUBLAS_OP_T,B.n_rows,B.n_cols,A.n_cols,A.p,A.n_rows,d_tau,B.p,B.n_rows,d_work,lwork,devInfo) );
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );
    // check if QR is good or not
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy(&info_gpu, devInfo, sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );
    confirm(info_gpu == 0,"Error: 'mld()' operation cannot be performed. QR decomposition failed.");

    // step 6: compute x = R \ (Q^T*B)
    HANDLE_ERROR( cublasDtrsm(cublas_handle,CUBLAS_SIDE_LEFT,CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_UPPER,CUBLAS_OP_N,CUBLAS_DIAG_NON_UNIT,A.n_cols,B.n_cols,&alf,A.p,A.n_rows,B.p,A.n_cols) );
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );

    // Free resources
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaFree(d_tau) );
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaFree(devInfo) );
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaFree(d_work) );

    HANDLE_ERROR( cublasDestroy(cublas_handle) );
    HANDLE_ERROR( cusolverDnDestroy(cusolver_handle) );

    return std::move(B);
}
/***************************************************************************************************************************/


/*****************************************   Matrix with all values 1   *****************************************/
cu_mat ones(const size_t &r, const size_t &c)
{
    cu_mat tmp(r,c,1); //tmp.del = 0;
    return std::move(tmp);
}
cu_mat ones(const size_t &n){return std::move(ones(n,n));}
/***************************************************************************************************************************/

/*****************************************   Matrix with all values 0   *****************************************/
cu_mat zeros(const size_t &r, const size_t &c)
{
    cu_mat tmp(r,c); //tmp.del = 0;
    return std::move(tmp);
}
cu_mat zeros(const size_t &n){return std::move(zeros(n,n));}
/***************************************************************************************************************************/


/***************************************   Transpose current matrix   *****************************************/
__global__ void mat_trans(double* a, double* b, size_t rows, size_t cols, size_t n_ele)
{
    unsigned int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    size_t r = idx%rows, c = idx/rows;
    if (idx<n_ele)
    a[c+r*cols] = b[idx];
}
cu_mat trans(cu_mat &a)
{
    cu_mat tmp(a.n_cols,a.n_rows);
    size_t n_ele = tmp.n_rows*tmp.n_cols;
    size_t n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
    mat_trans<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(tmp.p,a.p,a.n_rows,a.n_cols,n_ele);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    return std::move(tmp);
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/


/***************************************   Horizontal concatenation of two matrices   *****************************************/
cu_mat horzcat(cu_mat &a, cu_mat &b)
{
    confirm(a.n_rows==b.n_rows,"Error: Dimensions of arrays being horizontally concatenated are not consistent.");
    cu_mat tmp(a.n_rows,a.n_cols+b.n_cols);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy(tmp.p,a.p,a.n_rows*a.n_cols*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice) );
    size_t n_ele = b.n_rows*b.n_cols, n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
    copymat<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(tmp.p,b.p,a.n_cols*tmp.n_rows,tmp.n_rows,0,n_ele);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    return std::move(tmp);
}
/***************************************************************************************************************************/


/***************************************   Vertical concatenation of two matrices   *****************************************/
cu_mat vertcat(cu_mat &a, cu_mat &b)
{
    confirm(a.n_cols==b.n_cols,"Error: Dimensions of arrays being vertically concatenated are not consistent.");
    cu_mat tmp(a.n_rows+b.n_rows,a.n_cols);
    size_t n_ele = a.n_rows*a.n_cols, n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
    copymat<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(tmp.p,a.p,0,a.n_rows,tmp.n_rows-a.n_rows,n_ele);
    n_ele = b.n_rows*b.n_cols; n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
    copymat<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(tmp.p,b.p,a.n_rows,b.n_rows,tmp.n_rows-b.n_rows,n_ele);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    return std::move(tmp);
}
/***************************************************************************************************************************/


/***************************************   MATLAB colon operator   *****************************************/
__global__ void ss_mat_fill(double* dest, double i, double step, size_t n_ele)
{
    unsigned int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if(idx<n_ele)
    {
        dest[idx] = i+step*idx;
    }
}
cu_mat stepspace(const double &i, const double &f, const double &step=1)
{
    size_t n;
    if (((f-i)/step)>=0)
        n = (f-i)/step+1;
    else
        n = 0;
    cu_mat tmp(n,1);
    size_t n_ele = tmp.n_rows*tmp.n_cols, n_threads = block_dim(n_ele);
    ss_mat_fill<<<n_ele/n_threads,n_threads>>>(tmp.p,i,step,n_ele);
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    return std::move(tmp);
}
/***************************************************************************************************************************/


/************************************   Check if 'cu_mat' object is scalar   ***********************************************/
bool isscalar(const cu_mat &a)
{
    return ((a.n_rows*a.n_cols)==1);
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************/



//  Destructor
cu_mat::~cu_mat() {
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaFree(p) );
    p = NULL;
}
```

### block_dim.cu ## - Function to compute the block dimension for kernel calls

```
#include "imp_includes.hcu"

size_t block_dim(size_t n_ele)
{
    size_t tc;
    if (n_ele<=1024) return(n_ele);

    else if (n_ele%2==0){
        for (tc=1024;tc>1;tc=tc-2){
            if (n_ele%tc==0) return(tc);}}

    else{
        for (tc=1023;tc>1;tc=tc-2){
            if (n_ele%tc==0) return(tc);}}

    std::cout << "Warning: Calculations cannot be divided equally. Be careful when making the CUDA kernel." << std::endl;
    return(256);
}
```

### cu_error_list.cu ## - List of possible cuBLAS, cuRAND and cuSOLVER api errors.

```
#include "imp_includes.hcu"

// cuBLAS API errors
const char *cublasGetErrorString(cublasStatus_t err)
{
    switch (err) {
        case CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED:
          return "CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED";
        case CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED:
          return "CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED";
        case CUBLAS_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE:
          return "CUBLAS_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE";
        case CUBLAS_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH:
          return "CUBLAS_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH";
        // case CUBLAS_STATUS_MAPPING_err:
        //   return "CUBLAS_STATUS_MAPPING_err";
        case CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED:
          return "CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED";
        // case CUBLAS_STATUS_INTERNAL_err:
        //   return "CUBLAS_STATUS_INTERNAL_err";
        case CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED:
          return "CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED";
        // case CUBLAS_STATUS_LICENSE_err:
        //   return "CUBLAS_STATUS_LICENSE_err";
      }
      return "<unknown>";
}

  // cuSOLVER API errors
const char *cusolverGetErrorString(cusolverStatus_t err)
{
    switch (err) {
      case CUSOLVER_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED:
        return "CUSOLVER_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED";
      case CUSOLVER_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED:
        return "CUSOLVER_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED";
      case CUSOLVER_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE:
        return "CUSOLVER_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE";
      case CUSOLVER_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH:
        return "CUSOLVER_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH";
    //   case CUSOLVER_STATUS_MAPPING_err:
    //     return "CUSOLVER_STATUS_MAPPING_err";
      case CUSOLVER_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED:
        return "CUSOLVER_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED";
    //   case CUSOLVER_STATUS_INTERNAL_err:
    //     return "CUSOLVER_STATUS_INTERNAL_err";
      case CUSOLVER_STATUS_MATRIX_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED:
        return "CUSOLVER_STATUS_MATRIX_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED";
      case CUSOLVER_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED:
        return "CUSOLVER_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED ";
      case CUSOLVER_STATUS_ZERO_PIVOT:
        return "CUSOLVER_STATUS_ZERO_PIVOT";
      case CUSOLVER_STATUS_INVALID_LICENSE:
        return "CUSOLVER_STATUS_INVALID_LICENSE";
    }
    return "<unknown>";
}

  // cuRAND API errors
const char *curandGetErrorString(curandStatus_t err)
{
    switch (err) {
      case CURAND_STATUS_VERSION_MISMATCH:
        return "CURAND_STATUS_VERSION_MISMATCH";
      case CURAND_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED:
        return "CURAND_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED";
      case CURAND_STATUS_ALLOCATION_FAILED:
        return "CURAND_STATUS_ALLOCATION_FAILED";
    //   case CURAND_STATUS_TYPE_err:
    //     return "CURAND_STATUS_TYPE_err";
      case CURAND_STATUS_OUT_OF_RANGE:
        return "CURAND_STATUS_OUT_OF_RANGE";
      case CURAND_STATUS_LENGTH_NOT_MULTIPLE:
        return "CURAND_STATUS_LENGTH_NOT_MULTIPLE";
      case CURAND_STATUS_DOUBLE_PRECISION_REQUIRED:
        return "CURAND_STATUS_DOUBLE_PRECISION_REQUIRED";
      case CURAND_STATUS_LAUNCH_FAILURE:
        return "CURAND_STATUS_LAUNCH_FAILURE";
      case CURAND_STATUS_PREEXISTING_FAILURE:
        return "CURAND_STATUS_PREEXISTING_FAILURE";
      case CURAND_STATUS_INITIALIZATION_FAILED:
        return "CURAND_STATUS_INITIALIZATION_FAILED";
      case CURAND_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH:
        return "CURAND_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH";
    //   case CURAND_STATUS_INTERNAL_err:
    //     return "CURAND_STATUS_INTERNAL_err";
    }
    return "<unknown>";
}
```

### error_check.cu ## - Overloaded functions to convert errors into strings

```
#include "imp_includes.hcu"

//#define HANDLE_ERROR( err ) (HandleError( err, __FILE__, __LINE__ ))

void HandleError( cudaError_t err,const char *file,int line )
{
    confirm(err == cudaSuccess,cudaGetErrorString( err )<<" in "<<file<<" at "<<line<<".");
}

void HandleError( cublasStatus_t err,const char *file,int line )
{
    confirm(err == CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS,cublasGetErrorString( err )<<" in "<<file<<" at "<<line<<".");
}

void HandleError( cusolverStatus_t err,const char *file,int line )
{
    confirm(err == CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS,cusolverGetErrorString( err )<<" in "<<file<<" at "<<line<<".");
}

void HandleError( curandStatus_t err,const char *file,int line )
{
    confirm(err == CURAND_STATUS_SUCCESS,curandGetErrorString( err )<<" in "<<file<<" at "<<line<<".");
}
```

### cu_mat_test.cu ## - Main function to test the class

```
#include "cu_mat.hcu"
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    clock_t begin = clock();
    look_for_errors;

    cu_mat A = randn(5), b = randn(5,1);
    cu_mat c = mld(A,b);
    A.get(); b.get(); c.get();

    report_errors;
    clock_t end = clock();
    double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout << elapsed_secs << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### imp_includes.hcu ## - Macro definition for exception handling and included other required libraries

```
#ifndef IMP_INCLUDES_H_
#define IMP_INCLUDES_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <curand.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <cusolverDn.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <functional>

// Macro definitions
#define look_for_errors try{

#define report_errors }catch(int n){}

#define confirm(cond,err)                   \
if(!(cond))                                 \
{                                           \
    std::cout << "\a" << err << std::endl;  \
    throw 1;                                \
}

#define HANDLE_ERROR( err ) (HandleError( err, __FILE__, __LINE__ ))

// Extra functions
size_t block_dim(size_t n_ele);
const char *cublasGetErrorString(cublasStatus_t err);               // cuBLAS API errors
const char *cusolverGetErrorString(cusolverStatus_t err);           // cuSOLVER API errors
const char *curandGetErrorString(curandStatus_t err);               // cuRAND API errors
void HandleError( cudaError_t err,const char *file,int line );
void HandleError( cublasStatus_t err,const char *file,int line );
void HandleError( cusolverStatus_t err,const char *file,int line );
void HandleError( curandStatus_t err,const char *file,int line );
__global__ void copymat(double* dest, double* src, size_t bias, size_t src_rows, size_t main_rows_bias, size_t n_ele);

#endif /* IMP_INCLUDES_HCU_ */
```

Answer (score 2):

A few short comments:

1. Initializing a matrix with a compile-time list of values (initializer list) does not seem to be very useful - as CUDA is used to process huge amounts of data, not a tiny number of elements you provide at compile time.
2. Mixing code for mathematical / data structure abstractions with error handling utility code into the same class is not a good idea.
3. Your function and method names are often unnecessary shortened (like `mld`), ambiguous (`confirm`), or involve redundancy (like `cu_mat` instead of `matrix` in an appropriate namespace).
4. It looks like these are supposed to be matrices that are located in host memory, but copied back and forth to device memory for every single operation. Why is that a useful think to have?

PS - If you want to use more C++-ish error handling, you could consider my [CUDA API wrappers](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers) which do just that (and is obviously separated from any application-specific logic).